# How can I get the code to copy data from sheet2 to sheet1?

Tags: excel, vba

I got code to show the value of a variable, not copying to `Sheet1`. How do I get this to copy code to a new sheet?

I got code to show the address of a value and need it to copy to `Sheet1`.

```vb
Sub check_0_2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
        lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ws2.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = cell.Value
            Debug.Print "found in " & cell.Address
        End If
        lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It only shows a 0 in cell A1, and it should be more.

Comment: Your code will only copy 1 value, because your `lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` stops on the same point, add a  +1 at the end like this: `lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`. Thought why not filter Column A with the criteria = 0 and copy everything in one go instead looping?

Comment: thanks damian, that did the trick. had to use two lines to make it work though. +1 for you.